# Deleting row from Dataframe based on ANY column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of the sort:

```
    Plate | MeanV1 | MeanV2 | MeanV3 ...etc
-----------------------------------------------
0   1     |   3.2  |   4.8  |  6.8  |
1   1     |   3.1  |  10000 | 10000 |  
2   2     |   2.8  |   4.6  |  6.1  |
3   2     |   2.9  |   5.1  | 10000 |
4   3     |  10000 |   5.0  |  7.2  |
```

and need to be able to quickly drop all rows where ANY column contains 10000.

I had an earlier df which only featured the error code (the `10000`) in a single column, and could use:

```
df[df['MeanV1'] < 1000]
```

But the only way i've managed to perform this on multiple columns is just:

```
df[df['MeanV1'] < 1000]
df[df['MeanV2'] < 1000]
df[df['MeanV3'] < 1000]
```

etc.. Bearing in mind that in a real dataset there are over 3000 columns.

Can someone help me understand why:

```
headers = list(df)

for prop in headers:
    df = df[df[prop] < 1000]
```

does not work?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need also check first column `Plate` ?

Comment: Thanks for all these - sorry hadn't found the answer  - but could someone tell me why my approach doesn't work?

Comment: And no, don't need to check `Plate` - sorry that wasn't clear

Comment: I just ran your code, it executes correctly on pandas `0.23.3`

Comment: Thanks andrew_reece - I've just upgraded to 0.23.4 and it now works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select range of columns, here all without first,  compare by all values with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df =  df[(df.iloc[:, 1:] != 10000).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   Plate  MeanV1  MeanV2  MeanV3
0      1     3.2     4.8     6.8
2      2     2.8     4.6     6.1
```

Comment: Hmm, our answers are pretty close, I'm just going to make mine a comment on yours: also possible to use `ne`: `df[df.ne(10000).all(axis=1)]`