# Python code to remove all rows in a dataset that contain -1 anywhere in them

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, data-cleaning

I have the following code for a dataset I am trying to clean.  I need to remove several elements but currently removing any rows that contain -1 in them is causing some challanges.  I have tried a number of methods with mixed success.

```
 dir_name = "/temp/CIC2018"

 #Get a list of all CSV files in the directory
 csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_name, "*.csv"))

 #Initialize an empty list to hold dataframes
 dfs = []

 #Loop over all CSV files and append each one to the list

 for csv_file in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, low_memory=False)
    dfs.append(df)
    print("Number of CSV files:", len(csv_files))

 merged_df.to_csv("C:/temp/CIC2018/Output/CIC2018-Umodified-Merged.csv", index=False)

 print("Shape", merged_df.shape)

 print("Removing -1")
 df = df[~(df.isin([-1])).any(axis=1)]
 print("Removed -1 - Shape :",df.shape)
```

This seems to remove some of the rows, but when I open the file in notepad++ there are still a lot in there.

I have also tried

```
    rows_to_drop = merged_df[merged_df.applymap(lambda x: x == -1).any(axis=1)]
    merged_df.drop(index=rows_to_drop, inplace=True)
```

But this produces (I have removed a load of column to make this readable)

"['Dst Port', 'Protocol', 'Timestamp', 'Flow Duration', ... 'Idle Mean', 'Idle Std', 'Idle Max', 'Idle Min', 'Label'] not found in axis"
File "MergeCIC4.py", line 35, in 
merged_df.drop(index=rows_to_drop, inplace=True)

KeyError: "['Dst Port', 'Protocol', 'Timestamp', 'Flow Duration', ... 'Idle Mean', 'Idle Std', 'Idle Max', 'Idle Min', 'Label'] not found in axis"

I am reasonable with PowerShell, but this is my first time with Python, and I need to use Python for the AI training I am looking at doing, so I may be making a really simple mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just like any problems, let's make it simple first:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(5, 5)), columns=list('abcde'))

df.at[1, "b"] = int(-1)
df.at[4, "d"] = int(-1)

print(df)
```

You'd get something like:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0  55  30  90  51   1
1  43  -1  80  89  90
2  18  27  28  72   6
3  41  26  26  76  75
4  16  38  66  -1  72
```

Now we want to remove any rows that have -1 in it, which we expect to be row with index 1 and index 4, so now we do:

```py
# Original solution came from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51836883/6681261
dfnew =  df[(df.iloc[:, 1:] != -1).all(axis=1)]
print(df)
print(dfnew)
```

You'd get

```
>>> df
    a   b   c   d   e
0  55  30  90  51   1
1  43  -1  80  89  90
2  18  27  28  72   6
3  41  26  26  76  75
4  16  38  66  -1  72

>>> dfnew
    a   b   c   d   e
0  55  30  90  51   1
2  18  27  28  72   6
3  41  26  26  76  75
```

Comment: Thanks, I am giving that a try now.  Quick question.  Is there any reason I need to create it as a new df?  Can I just update the existing one using:

df = df[(df.iloc[:, 1:] != -1).all(axis=1)]

Comment: Whats interesting is I get the same results from my original line and the one suggested:


Initial try
Shape (8284254, 80)
Removing -1
Removed -1 - Shape : (5157793, 80)

Suggested update
Original Shape (8284254, 80)
Removing -1
Removed -1 - Shape : (5157793, 80)

There are still 438522 -1 entries in the file.

Comment: I just wanted to visualize the change in one script directly. But you can definitely update the original variable.