# How to keep a row if any column contains a certain substring?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame df:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Var1': ['d', 'a --> b', 'e', 'c --> d'],
                   'Var2': ['a', 'e', 'a --> b', 'd'],
                   'Var3': ['c', 'd', 'a --> b', 'e']})
```

Which looks like this when printed (for reference):

```
|   | Var1    | Var2    | Var3    |
|---|---------|---------|---------|
| 0 | d       | a       | c       |
| 1 | a --> b | e       | d       |
| 2 | e       | a --> b | a --> b |
| 3 | c --> d | d       | e       |
```

**I would like to keep just the rows 1, 2 and 3 that contains the value '-->'. In another words, I want to drop all rows in my dataframe that doesn't contains at least one column with the value '-->'.**

I know how to filter just one column, `df[df['Var1'].str.contains('-->', regex=False)]` like gives me rows 1 and 3.

But I don't know how to apply to all columns. And I read some similar cases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836849/deleting-row-from-dataframe-based-on-any-column-value?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914985/drop-a-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe-if-any-column-contains-a-certain-value-in-said), but couldn't figure out how to adapt to my case.

Can you suggest a way to select those rows?

Comment: the last row should be `c        d        e`  and not have `c --> d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter them out using this.

```
df1= df[df.apply(lambda x: any(x.str.contains('-->')),axis=1)]
print (df1)
```

The output of this will be:

Original DataFrame:

```
      Var1     Var2     Var3
0        d        a        c
1  a --> b        e        d
2        e  a --> b  a --> b
3        c        d        e
```

DF1: contains only rows with arrows

```
      Var1     Var2     Var3
1  a --> b        e        d
2        e  a --> b  a --> b
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine all columns into one and search for the substring:

```
df[df.sum(axis=1).str.contains('-->')]
#      Var1     Var2     Var3
#1  a --> b        e        d
#2        e  a --> b  a --> b
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me because my real df contains some NaN. It's beyond what I asked about, but do you know how to ignore them? I tried  `df[df.sum(axis=1).str.contains('-->') == True]`, but with no success.

Comment: Convert them to strings: `df.astype(str).sum...`

Answer (score 0):

try `.stack()` with a boolean index.

```
s = df.stack().str.contains('-->').reset_index(1,drop=True)

df.loc[s[s].index.unique()]


      Var1     Var2     Var3
1  a --> b        e        d
2        e  a --> b  a --> b
```