# Search across all columns using a wildcard

Tags: python, pandas

I have data with a variable number of columns. I want to be able to exclude all rows that contain any number ending "9999".

Sample input:

> ```
>     Customer Reference,Profile Name,Score,Band Text,Result1,Result2,Result3,Result4,Result5,Result6,Result7,Result8,Result9,Result10,Result11,Result12,Result13,Result14,Result15,Result16,Result17,Result18,Result19,Result20,Result21,Result22,Result23,Result24,Result25,Result26,Result27,Result28,Result29,Result30,Result31,Result32,Result33,Result34,Result35,Result36,Result37,Result38,Result39,Result40,Result41,Result42,Result43,Result44,Result45,Result46,Result47,Result48,Result49
> 038ff126-1ed5-4a96-bb34-3f4b595228d3,UK,1200,PASS - 2+2,155261,155101,155151,155161,155271,155251,1551001,1551101,1557031,1559500,1558101,395102,3953500,3952260,3952100,3952101,3952111,3953800,3953760,3953512,3953522,3956611,3959600,3959601,3963505,3963513,3963531,3963507,1062,2452,1332,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
> 87529660,Germany,1111,APPROVED,2289528,401126,401102,401423,401424,401426,4012100,4012101,4012111,4012260,4013500,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
> 37a52968-8093-41e5-8a2e-6bd251d0666d,UK,2200,PASS - 2+2,155261,155101,155151,155161,1551001,1551101,1551111,1551121,1551071,1551072,1553520,1556518,1557031,395102,3953500,3952260,3952100,3952101,3952111,3953512,3953521,3956760,3956600,3956601,3956611,3963504,3963508,3963512,3963526,3963529,3963500,3964510,1062,2452,1332,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
> 138629690,Germany,1111,APPROVED,2283524,2283525,2282111,2282100,2282101,2282263,2282264,2282266,2282260,4012,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
> 1d45f78b-01c5-4007-8f8c-a9fb845cba1f,UK,1300,PASS - 2+2,155261,155101,155151,155161,155131,1551001,1551011,1551021,1553508,1551101,1551111,1551121,1551071,1551072,1553522,3952,3962,1062,2452,1332,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
> a56b590b-b8bd-4e56-987e-f801a37e487d,UK,1300,PASS - 2+2,155261,155101,155151,155161,155131,1551001,1551011,1551021,1553508,1559999,1551111,1551121,1551071,1551072,1553522,1556514,3952,3962,1062,2452,1332,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
> 138888892,Germany,2221,APPROVED,2283525,2282111,2282100,2282101,2284530,2284266,2288263,2288264,2288260,401126,401102,401423,401424,401426,4012100,4012101,4012111,4012260,4013500,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
> ```

Please note that different files have different numbers of "Results" columns.

The only method I've been able to find that works is like this:

```
filter1 = data.Result1.astype(str).str.contains('9999')
filter2 = data.Result2.astype(str).str.contains('9999')
filter3 = data.Result3.astype(str).str.contains('9999')
filter4 = data.Result4.astype(str).str.contains('9999')
```

Then applying the filters like this

```
data.where(filter1 | filter2 | filter3 | filter4 ... etc
```

Obviously this is painful and I need to change the number of filters per file.

I'm sure there's probably a way to do this but I've not managed to find one.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat all of the Result* columns and search through that new column

```
clms_to_concat = [i for i in df.columns if 'Result' in i]
df['combined'] = ''
for c in clms_to_concat:
    df['combined'] = df['combined'] + '_' + df[c].astype(str) 
df[df.combined.str.contains('9999')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a combination of `replace` and `dropna`.
Partial answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914985/drop-a-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe-if-any-column-contains-a-certain-value-in-said):

1. First you replace all values ending by 9999 by np.nan's
2. You drop the NaN's

It should look something like that:

```py
df.replace('.9999',np.nan,regex=True).dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help.  This doesn't work because there are already lots of empty cells in the data, so dropping NaNs results in a nearly empty df

Comment: I understand, so in this case you could do this in 2 steps, assuming that the `Results` columns are only digits :
`df.replace('.*9999','XYZ',regex=True, inplance=True)` and then `df_final = df[(df.iloc[:, 1:] != 'XYZ').all(axis=1)]`

Comment: Don't I need to call "drop" somewhere? I still have the same number of rows as the original file

Comment: I didn't realise the previous comment worked only for string types... This time I tried with your actual sample input, and I do get one line removed: 
`df.astype(str).replace('.*9999','XYZ',regex=True, inplace=False)` and then as previously `df_final = df[(df.iloc[:, 1:] != 'XYZ').all(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 0):

The following approach considers only `Result`-labeled columns and filters out the rows where those columns values end with `9999`:

```
df[~df.filter(like='Result').astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str[-4:] == '9999').any(1)]
```

---

```
                     Customer Reference Profile Name  Score   Band Text  ...  Result46  Result47  Result48  Result49
0  038ff126-1ed5-4a96-bb34-3f4b595228d3           UK   1200  PASS - 2+2  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1                              87529660      Germany   1111    APPROVED  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2  37a52968-8093-41e5-8a2e-6bd251d0666d           UK   2200  PASS - 2+2  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
3                             138629690      Germany   1111    APPROVED  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
4  1d45f78b-01c5-4007-8f8c-a9fb845cba1f           UK   1300  PASS - 2+2  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
6                             138888892      Germany   2221    APPROVED  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping.  This seems to filter out some, but not all, of the affected records. My first thought is perhaps there are some white space or other characters in the fields? How would you alter the lambda to apply to '9999' in any position within the string? The first file has 452 errors from 10k records, your code removes 152 of them. I can't understand why the others aren't also working

Comment: @brummie49 `x.str.contains('9999')`